# How to get category-id in a module when using SEO in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I use Joomla >= 2.5 and SEO

To look up informations in a database, i would like to get the category-id of the content shown on the page.

Without SEO i used:

```
$uri = & JFactory::getURI();
$view = $uri->getVar('view');
$cat_id = $uri->getVar('id');
$item_id = $uri->getVar('Itemid');
```

how do i get this information while using SEO?

Comment: Did you try same when SEF urls are enabled?

Comment: Yes. But SEF-Routed URIs do not have these variables. So i can't fumble them out of the URI. I wonder if there is a more robust way to do that in joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the way to get the id of the category, when SEO is used:

```
$catId = JRequest::getInt('id', null, 'get');
```